# Is there a macOS command line tool for converting eps or ps files to pdf?

Tags: macos, pdf, postscript, eps

I have some eps files that I would like to convert to PDF. I used to be able to open these in Preview, but [Apple has removed the ability of Preview to open EPS files in Ventura](https://www.macrumors.com/2022/10/25/macos-ventura-preview-app-drops-postscript-support/).

Answer (score 13):

macOS has a command line `pstopdf` that will work with both `ps` and `eps` files.

`pstopdf <filename>.ps`

will produce `<filename>.pdf`.

`man pstopdf` for more details.

Comment: This tool is not included anymore in latest versions in Sonoma

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest way to get the `ps2pdf` utility back in Sonoma and forward is by installing `ghostscript` via Homebrew

```
brew install ghostscript
```

Here's an example (create a PDF of the `ls` manpage)

```
man -t ls | ps2pdf - /tmp/ls.pdf &&
open -b com.apple.Preview /tmp/ls.pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

I discovered this after updating macOS yesterday. Thanks to [@dmaclach’s answer](https://superuser.com/a/1769825/62267), I found [PostScriptToPDF](https://mendelson.org/postscripttopdf.html) by Edward Mendelson, which is a wrapper for `pstopdf` as an AppleScript application. This offers a few conveniences, namely: an “Open” dialog, drag & drop, and file type associations—if you associate it with `.ps` files in Finder (under “Open With” in the contextual menu or “Get Info” panel) then double-clicking a PostScript file will quietly convert it to PDF.

Note that PostScriptToPDF will request permission to control “System Events”, which is no cause for alarm—that’s an application provided by Apple so that AppleScript programs can perform folder actions on your behalf. In this case, it allows the option of automatically deleting the PS file after successful conversion. You can deny the request without issue if you won’t use that feature.